# Placeholder is not hiding when value selected in ng-select Angular

Tags: angular

I am using ng-select in one of my angular application but after selecting the value from ng select the placeholder is not hiding. can anyone help me with this?

without using ngModel with this css it is woking fine

but the moment I am using ngModel it is not working.

[image]

```
::ng-deep.ng-select .ng-has-value .ng-placeholder {
   display: none;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are still having this issue, removing the `::ng-deep` selector works for me.
Your CSS style becomes

```
.ng-select .ng-has-value .ng-placeholder {    display: none;  }
```